# Is IntelliJ 10 Ultimate edition a good tool for a GWT project?

Tags: gwt, maven, intellij-idea

I'm thinking of using IntelliJ+Maven+GWT. I'd like to create/build project using maven and do all the editing in ItelliJ. Could anyone share experience using similar stack? Eclipse seems to be a default choice for GWT, but I'm a big fan of IntelliJ so would prefer to continue using it. I think I can live without WYSWYG editor, if the rest is good.

Would be nice to get some feedback before I pay for the licence.

thanks

Comment: I've successfully used IntelliJ for a project involving GWT. The same features as in Eclipse are available (i.e. debugger, etc.). I'm afraid that's a bit of a subjective question, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea has even more features connected to GWT development, but in some minor cases support is broken (I faced some issues connected to UiBinder: wrong templates, wrong uifields for html elements, some extra unnecessary warnings/errors)

Integration with maven works also fine.

So, it's a good choice if you are fine with Idea

Answer (score 2):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but I found this great blog post about getting started with gwt-maven-intellij, and wanted to share it:

http://antonkirillov.wordpress.com/2011/03/22/creating-and-running-gwt-project-using-maven-and-intellij-idea-10/

Answer (score 1):

If you're good enough in GWT and you have previously worked on some projects, than you can use whatever IDE or editor you want :)

Google plugin though is really comfortable to have in Eclipse, so if you don't have much experience I'd recommend to stick with Eclipse. Or you can write core code with IntelliJ, put that on SVN, update to Eclipse, use f.e. WYSIWYG designer or run in development mode and so on ...

If you're not in hurry I'd suggest following some tutorials for Eclipse (google-code site has some) and then try it yourself with IntelliJ to see how does that work for you.

Comment: GWT support is the same in IntelliJ as in Eclipse. Can you give examples of missing features?

Comment: I don't say IDEA isn't good enough of course! I've just tried to point out, that if you are beginner, there are most of tutorials on the internet using GPE and you get stuff for free like GWT Designer (good for early orientation), app engine has nice set of tools in GPE, you can directly connect google accounts and easily use another google APIs ... You know nothing GREAT compared to IDEA, but interesting enough ;)